# Tor browser - Failed to establish a Tor network connection

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, tor

I have tried to use Tor inside corporate IT network with firewall restrictions. Now it shows Failed to establish a Tor network connection. How can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 3):

When the error message appears, you may get an option to "copy Tor log to clipboard".
Copy and paste the log into a text file and view the error message.

You may find a list of the possible error and their cause in the article
[I am having trouble connecting to Tor](https://support.torproject.org/connecting/connecting-2/),
but most likely the error is "Failed to find node",
which means that your company is censoring Tor on its network.

I would first counsel that going against company policy can have serious
consequences for yourself. I would suggest first finding out if the company
network administrator is not actively against using Tor.

If Tor is acceptable for your company, and the problem is only technical,
you could try to get Tor bridges from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges) or sending an email to `bridges@torproject.org` and [add it to your Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#UsingBridges).
Bridges are Tor relays that aren't listed in the publicly available list.
Make sure to add at least one bridge with port number 443 and one with a
random port.

If bridges didn't help, you could use the [Pluggable Transport Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#download).

Comment: " would first counsel that going against company policy can have serious consequences for yourself." ++1